# STM32F303K8 - unable to control duty cycle of slave timer

Tags: timer, stm32

**Abstract:** I can not control the duty cycle of a PWM generated by the slave timer in a Master/Slave configuration on an STM32F303K8

What I am trying to achieve is to start two timers synchronously. The Master timer (TIM1) should generate a PWM, with a variable duty cycle; the other timer (the slave, TIM3) should output sharp pulses. Master and Slave should start synchronously; The base frequency of Timer 1 should be 12.5kHz, the base Frequency of Timer 3 should be 1 kHz.
The Problem: While starting the two timers synchronously works perfectly, I can enter whatever values for timer period and pulse width on Timer 3: the duty cycle is always 50% (which is equal to the duty cycle of Timer 1) and the base frequency of Timer 3 is the same as the base frequency (period) of Timer 1, as seen in this screenshot from the scope.
As this is just a simple test program, I used my Nucleo F303 and hacked some quick solution, based on HAL. The only purpose of this test is to check, how I can start two timers with different base frequencies and duty cycles synchronously. The final solution will be used on an G473.

The assumption is: if I get this configured correctly on the F303 using HAL-Drivers, it should also work on a G473. The second assumption is, that – as both base clocks for both timers are derived from the system clock – if both timers had the same base frequency (period), they would stay in synch “forever”!? I’m pretty sure that the last statement is correct, but if someone could confirm that from his/her experience, that would be great.

**The Question(s):**

- a) does anyone detect a mistake / error in the config below, that
  would lead to the behaviour as described above?
- b) Can anyone confirm or decline my 2nd assumption?

The configuration from CubeMX:
[image: Pinout]

[image: Scope]

Blue: Output of Channel 4 of Timer 1 (Master).

Yellow: Output of Channel 1 of Timer 3 (Slave).

This is behaviour as expected, Timer 3 start on the first overflow of Timer 1.

[image: Timer 1 general Setup]

[image: Timer 1 Channel Setup]

[image: Timer 1 PWM]

[image: Timer 3 General Setuo]

[image: Timer 3 PWM Setup]

[image: Timer 3 Duty Cycle]

All the Programm does is to start the Timers once, then it goes into an empty while(1). The interrupt is used to toggle the LED on the Nucleo - just as visualisation, that the programm is running.

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

HAL_Delay(100);

HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_4); // start Timer 1 Ch 4 with Interrupt
```

Comment: Read out and check/post content of TIM1 and TIM3 registers, just after you've configured / before enabled them. On which pins do you measure? You may want to read out and check/post also content of the related GPIO registers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

you need to put the Scope Probe on the correct pin! This does the trick.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. If everything was working all along, and you were just probing the wrong pin, you might as well delete the question.

Comment: i'm ambiguous about deleting it. On the one hand it is a nice tutorial how to start two timers synchronously on an STM32, on the other hand the problem was located between the ears, not in the software ... I'd leave that decision to the admins / mods. I am not mad, if it gets deleted. Eventually I'll make a tutorial from it then ...